# Does this function have a name? $f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k} z^k$?

Tags: functions, power-series

Let
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k} z^k$$

This series converges absolutely for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, by comparison with $e^z$. Is there a name for $f$? I typed it into Wolfram, but no dice. Didn't really know where else to look since it's difficult to google for latex code.